# Is there an equivalent to dplyr::between for character vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am using a tibble, and I want to extract rows between two regular expressions.

First, I make a new column where I detect the regular expressions, and mark them.

```
tib <- tibble::tibble(
    x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
    y = c(F, T, F, T, F)
)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <lgl>
1 a     FALSE
2 b     TRUE 
3 c     FALSE
4 d     TRUE 
5 e     FALSE
```

Expected result:

```
tib %>% 
    dplyr::filter(
        dplyr::between(x, T, T)
    )

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <lgl>
1 b     TRUE 
2 c     FALSE
3 d     TRUE
```

`dplyr::between()` is used for number vectors, however. Anyway, it doesn't return the rows between two TRUE objects.

Is there an equivalent to `dplyr::between()` for character vectors? Or maybe there is another way someone might suggest that uses the boolean objects I have created.

Regards,

Comment: Can there more than 2 `TRUE`s ? Or just 1? What would be the expected output?

Comment: Hi, @markus, the expected result is written beneath  my command piping `tib` to `dplyr::filter`. There will be just two `TRUE`s for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind would be `slice` in combination with `which`˙, for example:

```
library(dplyr)

tib %>%
  slice(first(which(x == 'b')):last(which(x == 'd')))
```

Or with `y` itself:

```
tib %>%
  slice(first(which(y)):last(which(y)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <lgl>
1 b     TRUE 
2 c     FALSE
3 d     TRUE
```

Comment: This one maintains pipes most. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to get the indices of `TRUE` and create the sequence, i.e.

```
v1 <- which(tib$y)
tib[v1[1]:tail(v1, 1),]

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <lgl>
1 b     TRUE 
2 c     FALSE
3 d     TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you understand that function right. But you could use `regexpr`.

```
r <- regexpr("TFT", paste(substr(as.character(tib$y), 1, 1), collapse=""))
tib[r:(r + attr(r, "match.length") - 1), ]
#   x     y
# 2 b  TRUE
# 3 c FALSE
# 4 d  TRUE
```

Comment: I'm just trying to use it as an analogy here.

Comment: @iich Yeah, but `between` looks up which values are between lower and upper boundary, rather than between two appearances of a value, you know. Read `?between`.